# Can we develop a new kind of principles?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

We have a basic equation $F=ma$. Now can we change this equation to another variable and start a new era in physics? If so, then how? If not, then why?

Comment: Very rough question... There are two most noticeable formulations of classical mechanics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics

Answer (score 4):

$F=ma$ has not been the 'fundamental equation' of physics for a *long* time. In the advanced theories of modern physics, the concept of 'force' is no longer emphasized. Instead, we think about energy principles a lot more. The Lagrangian and Hamiltonian approaches are the most used approaches that embody this way of thinking.